# Laravel 8 ErrorException "stream_get_meta_data() expects parameter 1 to be resource, bool given"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

i just installing Laravel 8's JetStream LiveWire using Laravel Installer

```
Laravel new FoM
```

and

```
composer require laravel/jetstream
```

and then

```
php artisan jetstream:install livewire
```

like the Laravel 8's documentary said
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication

but when i tried /dashboard and upload a picture as a profile picture and then i got this error

> ErrorException
> stream_get_meta_data() expects parameter 1 to be resource, bool given
> http://fom.test/livewire/message/profile.update-profile-information-form

you can see the error here: https://flareapp.io/share/v5p9V6mE
i don't know how to fix this, when i find on google i just found old thread.

Answer (score 0):

@Dae,

You need to check your npm has installed or not If not than Please install it.

Run `npm install`

`npm install && npm run dev`

---------------------------- OR -----------------------

If you have laravel installer than directly you  can add jetStream package with below command.

`laravel new kitetail --jet`

kitetail is test project name you can add your project name.